# Background image not showing in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a background image with `background-attachment: fixed`, which works fine in all browsers in localhost but does not show in chrome on the server.

```
.bg-contact{
  background-image: url(../images/bg-contact.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Please help

Comment: How do you suppose us to answer that? Based upon assumptions!!

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: @ankitbug94  am sorry i did't add code snippets initially, i did ask it using thier app which doesn't have that funtionality

Answer (score 0):

Check the file extensions for the background, remember that capital letters make difference for example on your PC JPG and jpg is the same thing but on the server those are completely 2 different pictures.

Also include link to the website or add the code of it if you have problems with it.

-----New Idea For Answer------

You have:
 background-image:url(../images/bg-contact.jpg);

1. Make it with a full path to the file
2. Use Chrome Developer Tools from your Chrome Browser to get to inspect the element where picture should be displayed, then check if the value of background-image is:

   -Not crossed: then is should be working and it is not a problem with a code but with the browser.

   -It is crossed: Then your background property is not working, you can add !important to it to get a quick fix but you should find the reason behind it and fix it asap.

Comment: have checked, everything is intact

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache on that Chrome.

There's also an extraneous `{` which maybe Chrome is sensitive to.

Couple more things: try adding ' ' as in `('../images/bg-contact.jpg')`, and check AdBlock in Chrome.

Comment: that is not the cause because i have tried it on several devices. anyway did that and still not working

Comment: The fact that it works on all devices but that one is why it might have been the cache on that browser.

Comment: It does not work on any device so far as you are using chrome

Comment: Sorry was a typo

Answer (score -1):

Turned to be path issue, especially for Wordpress. When one is setting

```
background-image: url('bg_1.jpg');
```

in his `themes/myTheme` Folder, the browser is loading from `http://127.0.0.1:80/wordpress/bg_1.jpg`
, while the file is actualy in `C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\myTheme` [image: See Browser Dev Tools]
[image]
That is why one should say:

```
background-image: url('res/bg_1.jpg');
```

and make new folder `wordpress/res` in which bg_1.jpg will reside.